# How do I disable user input in a batch-file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Here's the code:

```
@echo off
color 0a

    set /p object="Name an object (article included): "
    set /p person="Name a person: "
    set /p place="Name a place: "
    
    echo %person% decided it was a good idea to take %object% to %place%. It was not.
    set /p DUMMY=Hit Enter to proceed.
```

I would like to make it so that when the `Hit Enter to proceed` part shows up, you can't type anything, until you pressed Enter.

Comment: It appears to me as if you're somehow expecting us to change how a built-in command works. The `Set /P` prompt already remains on screen until the `[ENTER]` key has been pressed, so what you appear to want is for `Set /P` not to show anything you type into it. This site helps you to fix an issue with your provided command/code, however, your command is working exactly as it was designed. Why does your end user have to specifically press the `[ENTER]` key, as opposed to any key, _(as with `Pause` or `timeout.exe /T -1`)_.

Comment: If the user presses any key other than Enter, it's possible the program will break. I'd rather not take any risks. If there's another command you know to fix the issue, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MadTurltess, no it is not possible to break anything, the end user can enter anything they want at the `Set /P` prompt, but nothing happens until they press the `ENTER` key. There is however no way that this could break your batch file though, and I also do not understand how `[any|a] key` with pause or timeout.exe could either. Perhaps you could extend your code to show us the issue you think you have, because I cannot envisage one. The only way you would have issues doing it with your particular code is if you then decided to use `%DUMMY%`, which is not required, `Set /P "=Press [ENTER]>"`.

Comment: Why not just use `pause` (or `pause >nul` if you don't like the "Press any key to continue..." output)? The script will wait until the user presses a key and not take any additional input from that command. The key that the user presses is also not stored anywhere, so there is zero chance of them breaking your script from this.

Comment: `set /P _="Hit {Enter} to proceed..." && (echo Hey, you entered something. Don't!) || (echo Great, you just pressed {Enter}.)`

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Perhaps you may be wrong when you said "it's possible the program will break" when the user enter "anything" as response in a `set /P` command. Anyway, this code do what you want:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get a CR
for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%~F0" NUL') do set "CR=%%a"

set /P "=Hit Enter to proceed. " < NUL

:getKey
set "key="
for /F "delims=" %%K in ('xcopy /W "%~F0" "%~F0" 2^>NUL') do (
   if not defined key set "key=%%K"
)
if "!key:~-1!" neq "!CR!" goto getKey

echo/
echo Proceeding...
```